# Angular HTTP interceptor for Authentication header

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I have to put a token inside the 'Authorization' header for every HTTP request.
So I have developed and registered an HttpInterceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public authService: AuthService) {
  }  

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let modifiedReq;
    const token = this.authService.getToken();

    // we need the heck clone because the HttpRequest is immutable
    // https://angular.io/guide/http#immutability
    if (token) {
      modifiedReq = request.clone();
      modifiedReq.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    }

    return next.handle(modifiedReq ? modifiedReq : request).pipe(tap(() => {
        // do nothing
    },
    (err: any) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (err.status === 0) {
        alert('what the heck, 0 HTTP code?');
      }
      if (err.status !== 401) {
        return;
      }
      this.authService.goToLogin();
    }
  }));
 }
}
```

But the header seems never to be put on the request sent. What am I doing wrong?

Also, sometimes an errorcode '0' gets caught by the interceptor; what does it mean?

Angular 8.2.11

**EDIT 1: ------------------------**

I've also tried like this:

```
request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });
```

but still no header has been set. 
Also, the module is correctly registered in app.module

```
 providers: [{
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: TokenInterceptor ,
   multi: true,
 }..
```

**EDIT 2 : ------------------------**

[image: debugger]

Check this image... I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. When doing update of the clone request, angular will put the new headers in fields called "**lazyUpdate**" and not direcly inside the headers. 
The requests were failing because of other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forget to put in `app.module` this:

```
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptor ,
    multi: true,
  }..
```

the final part write in this way:

```
 return next.handle(modifiedReq);
```

Comment: nope, it has been correctly registered. the code does pass to that interceptor but the header is not set.

Comment: @gaetatno if you do console.log(token), it prints the value or it is empty or null??

Comment: it prints stuff

Comment: the request.headers seems to not have the value set in any way I try

Comment: ti think the problem is whne you do if(token) because if token is null or empty is correct that you don't have the value in the header, but if token is not null it strange

Comment: @Gaetano i modify

Comment: Sorry, nothing has changed.

Comment: mi dispiace cavolo!

Comment: aspetta un'attimo ma io nella tua console ( che hai mesos nell'immagine) leggo un altro codice

Comment: ho provato a mattere il codice che mi ha consigliato LuisR, ma anche con il tuo non va...

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me like this:

```
const headersConfig = {
  'Accept': 'application/json', //default headers
};
...

if (token) {
  headersConfig['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
}
...

return next
  .handle(request.clone({
     setHeaders: headersConfig
  }))
```

Comment: you dont need modifiedRequest if you do like i show